# How to set a value if certain columns are the same across multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, update, window-functions

I am doing a data migration and I end up with a temporary table as follows:

```
curid cuid  rtid    cd          dd      rm
10     4    4   2016-01-02  2016-07-02  
16     4    4   2016-06-12  2016-12-12  Remarks Jun 12
18     5    3   2016-07-18  2017-07-31  
8      5    3   2015-06-21  2016-06-30  Add some test
11     6    4   2017-01-01  2017-07-01  
9      7    3   2017-01-01  2018-01-31
```

I need to split the data into two tables.
Based on that same data, it should look like this:

```
Table A
    id  curid cuid  rtid
    1    10    4    4   
    2    18    5    3   
    3    11    6    4   
    4     9    7    3
```

That's one row per distinct `(cuid, rtid)` plus a `curid` value picked from each set of duplicates. `id` is just a sequential number.

```
Table B
    id curid    cd           dd         rm
    1   10     2016-01-02   2016-07-02  
    2   10     2016-06-12   2016-12-12  Remarks Jun 12
    3   18     2016-07-18   2017-07-31  
    4   18     2015-06-21   2016-06-30  Add some test
    5   11     2017-01-01   2017-07-01  
    6    9     2017-01-01   2018-01-31
```

The actual `curid` is irrelevant as long as the records in `Table B` match the associated record in `Table A` (so we could even use a temp sequence or something to set the `curid`).

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer. I still think a window function should solve this problem but I can't figure out how to set and then match the curid for both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your test setup

(Best provided this way *in your question* - hint!)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp (
  curid int
, cuid  int
, rtid  int
, cd    date
, dd    date
, rm    text);

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES
  (10, 4, 4, '2016-01-02', '2016-07-02', NULL)  
 ,(16, 4, 4, '2016-06-12', '2016-12-12', 'Remarks Jun 12')
 ,(18, 5, 3, '2016-07-18', '2017-07-31', NULL)  
 ,(8 , 5, 3, '2015-06-21', '2016-06-30', 'Add some test')
 ,(11, 6, 4, '2017-01-01', '2017-07-01', NULL)
 ,(9 , 7, 3, '2017-01-01', '2018-01-31', NULL);
```

#### Solution

Create target tables if they don't exist:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE a (
   id    serial
 , curid int  -- UNIQUE?
 , cuid  int
 , rtid  int
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE b (
   id    serial
 , curid int
 , cd    date
 , dd    date
 , rm    text
);
```

Use `DISTINCT ON` for **table A**:

```
INSERT INTO a (curid, cuid, rtid)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cuid, rtid)
       curid, cuid, rtid
FROM   tmp
ORDER  BY  cuid, rtid, curid  -- pick smallest curid per group
RETURNING *;
```

```
id | curid | cuid | rtid
-: | ----: | ---: | ---:
 1 |    10 |    4 |    4
 2 |     8 |    5 |    3
 3 |    11 |    6 |    4
 4 |     9 |    7 |    3
```

Detailed explanation here:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Use a simple window function for **table B**:

```
INSERT INTO b (curid, cd, dd, rm)
SELECT min(curid) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid, rtid), cd, dd, rm
FROM   tmp
ORDER  BY cuid, rtid  -- optional
RETURNING *;
```

```
id | curid | cd         | dd         | rm            
-: | ----: | :--------- | :--------- | :-------------
 1 |    10 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-07-02 | null          
 2 |    10 | 2016-06-12 | 2016-12-12 | Remarks Jun 12
 3 |     8 | 2016-07-18 | 2017-07-31 | null          
 4 |     8 | 2015-06-21 | 2016-06-30 | Add some test 
 5 |    11 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-07-01 | null          
 6 |     9 | 2017-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | null
```

`curid` is guaranteed to match since we picked the smallest per group in both queries.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=07d88b5a1152e51d0a9e5a09ad70d19e)*

Comment: @Lee: Consider the update. Next time, rather *start a new question* than changing the nature of the existing one after answers have been given - even if you realize you asked the wrong question, that's irrelevant for the general public.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that you so much for teaching how to better ask questions and for teaching me how to be a better developer. This is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [dense_rank()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

```
create table tmp (curid int, cuid int, rtid int) ;

insert into temp
values
    (176,231,23),
    (192,231,23),
    (145,231,23),
    (122,231,23),
    (122,231,24),
    (122,231,25) ;

select dense_rank() over (order by cuid, rtid) as curid,
       cuid, 
       rtid
from temp ;
```

Answer (score 0):

With clarification, what I'd do in Microsoft SQL is,

```
SELECT cuid, rtid, IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS curid,
COUNT(*) AS how_many
INTO another_table
FROM original_table 
GROUP BY cuid, rtid
ORDER BY cuid, rtid
```

That creates a new table [another_table] of every combination of (cuid, rtid), with a row id in the new table.

Now, how much of that works in PostgreSQL?